# How to display a non-blocking warning for the operating system in Wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I already block installation of our software on operating systems where it is known not to work like this:

```
<Condition Message="This software needs Windows XP or newer.">
   <![CDATA[VersionNT >= 501]]>
</Condition>
```

Now I would also like to **display a non-blocking warning** if the user tries to install the software on an operating system (VersionNT + Service Pack) that is not explicitly supported, even though it *might* work.

For example, we only explicitly support the latest service pack of each operating system.

How can I display such a warning?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tackled this problem in 3 parts:

1. defining an OSWarningText property
   which is only set when a warning
   needs to be given
2. authoring a custom warning screen
3. Inserting the custom warning screen in the UI sequence if necessary

**1. Defining an OSWarningText property**

First, declare the property and give it the "unset" value by default:

```
  <Property Id="OSWarningText" Value="{}"/>
```

To construct the actual value of the property, set an intermediary property for each possible warning. Make sure the conditions for each warning do not overlap:

```
  <SetProperty Id="OSWarningText1" After="AppSearch"
     Value="Detected XP SP [ServicePackLevel]. SP3 or higher is recommended.">
     <![CDATA[(VersionNT = 501) AND NOT (ServicePackLevel >= 3)]]>
  </SetProperty>

  <SetProperty Id="OSWarningText2" After="SetOSWarningText1"
     Value="Detected Vista SP [ServicePackLevel]. SP2 or higher is recommended.">
     <![CDATA[(VersionNT = 600) AND NOT (ServicePackLevel >= 2)]]>
  </SetProperty>
```

Assuming the conditions don't overlap, we can safely condense the warnings in a single property like this:

```
  <SetProperty Id="OSWarningText" After="SetOSWarningText2"
     Value="[OSWarningText1][OSWarningText2]" />
```

**2. Authoring a custom warning screen.**

This is similar to the [example for adding a checkbox for the desktop shortcut](http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/). Copy one of the existing dialog definitions from the [wix sources](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=wix30#), e.g. `InstallDirDlg.wxs` and rename it to `WarningDlg.wxs`.

Set the dialog ID to `Id="WarningDlg`. Strip out the unnecessary controls and replace them by a warning image and our previously defined OSWarningText:

```
<Control Id="OSWarning" Type="Text" X="100" Y="80" Width="250" Height="60"
    NoPrefix="yes" Text="[OSWarningText]" />

<Control Id="WarningIcon" Type="Icon" X="20" Y="60" Width="64" Height="64"
   Text="Warning.ico" >
   <Binary Id="Warning.ico" SourceFile="..\icons\warning.ico"/>
</Control>
```

The idea is to create something like this:

[image]

**3. Inserting the custom warning screen in the UI sequence**

Now we need to make sure that the warning screen is displayed between the welcome dialog and the license agreement dialog, but only if there actually is a warning to show. This is a special case of the more general [branching wizard sequences](http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/branching-wizard-sequences-with-wix/) problem.

Again, copy a predefined UI sequence from the wix sources, e.g. `WixUI_InstallDir.wxs` and rename the UI ID to `Id="MyWixUI"`. Reference this in your main wxs file as `<UIRef Id="MyWixUI" />`. Now find and edit the event handlers for the WelcomeDlg next button.

You can set properties in response to a button press and an extra condition, and you can show the next dialog based on a property. We'll make use of that to handle the WelcomeDlg next button like this:

1. reset the WelcomeDlg_Next property
   to "unset"
2. set the WelcomeDlg_Next property to
   "WarningDlg" but only if
   OSWarningText is set
3. set the WelcomeDlg_Next property to
   "LicenseAgreementDlg" but only if
   OSWarningText is NOT set.
4. Show the dialog given by
   WelcomeDlg_Next, if the property was
   correctly set.

The Wix code to do that looks like this:

```
        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next"
            Property="WelcomeDlg_Next" Value="{}"
            Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next"
            Property="WelcomeDlg_Next" Value="WarningDlg"
            Order="2">OSWarningText</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next"
            Property="WelcomeDlg_Next" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg"
            Order="3">NOT OSWarningText</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next"
            Event="NewDialog" Value="[WelcomeDlg_Next]"
            Order="4">WelcomeDlg_Next</Publish>
```

Then do the equivalent for the License Agreement "back" button: it should go back to the welcome screen if there is no warning, or else to the warning screen.