# Wix Custom Dialog

Tags: wix

We are currently having the Classic theme of (Wix) for our installer wizard. Now, we have plan to improve the look and feel of the installer.

1) How i can change the custom dialog classic themes to something else.

2) While installing our setup we have plan to show the some images like slide show. Is it possible to show the images like that in the Wix. Whether I have to create any custom trigger to show the images. Please can you show some examples on this ?

Comment: Can you please post the code which worked for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How i can change the custom dialog
>   classic themes to something else.

Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810910/how-to-display-a-non-blocking-warning-for-the-operating-system-in-wix/1814103#1814103) where I walk through the things you need to do to create a custom warning dialog and insert it in a custom UI sequence.

> While installing our setup we have
>   plan to show the some images like
>   slide show. Is it possible to show the
>   images like that in the Wix. Whether I
>   have to create any custom trigger to
>   show the images

This is what the [BillBoardAction](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_billboardaction.htm) and [BillBoard](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_billboard.htm) elements are for. To display bitmaps during the installation of files, I think you would put something like this in the [UI](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_ui.htm) sequence definition (I haven't tested it):

```
  <BillboardAction Id="InstallFiles">
    <Billboard Id="FirstBillboard" Feature="FeatureA">
      <Control Id="FirstBitmap" Type="Bitmap" 
          Height="300" Width="300" X="0" Y="0">
        <Binary Id="HelloWorld.bmp" SourceFile="setupImages\HelloWorld.bmp"/>
      </Control>
    </Billboard>
    <Billboard Id="SecondBillboard" Feature="FeatureB">
      <Control Id="SecondBitmap" Type="Bitmap"
          Height="300" Width="300" X="0" Y="0">
        <Binary Id="HelloAgain.bmp" SourceFile="setupImages\HelloAgain.bmp"/>
      </Control>
    </Billboard>      
  </BillboardAction>
```