# Using Billboards in WIX

Tags: wix

I am trying to use a billboard in a WIX msi project. I looked all over the internet and the closest I got was [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764432/wix-custom-dialog/2764834#2764834).

I am trying to do exactly what has been mentioned in that solution.

I get a warning telling me that:

- The X coordinate exceeds the boundary of the minimum billboard control width 0
- The Y coordinate exceeds the boundary of the minimum billboard control height 0

(Google told me these warning are ICE95 checks which compares the Control and the BBControl table)

Also, for some reason the Billboards are not added to the controls table, when the msi is viewed using Orca.

I think I am missing something really silly here. I would appreciate any kind of input.

I am using the following code inside of UI tags for a custom WIXUI_InstallDir(WIXUI_InstallDir1):

```
<BillboardAction Id="InstallFiles">             
                <Billboard Id="FirstBillboard" Feature="MainApplication">
                    <Control Id="FirstBitmap" Type="Bitmap"
                        Height="50" Width="50" X="10" Y="10" FixedSize="yes">
                        <Binary Id="HelloWorld.bmp" SourceFile="srcfiles\gr.bmp"/>                          
                    </Control>

                </Billboard>
                <Billboard Id="SecondBillboard" Feature="SupportFiles">
                    <Control Id="SecondBitmap" Type="Bitmap"
                        Height="50" Width="50" X="10" Y="10" FixedSize="yes">
                        <Binary Id="HelloAgain.bmp" SourceFile="srcfiles\za.bmp"/>                          
                    </Control>
                </Billboard>
            </BillboardAction>
```

Comment: Avoid addressing your question directly to someone - you're asking the community, not a single person.

Answer (score 0):

Add BillBoard control to the dialog on which you want to view the images.

Code Snippets:

```
 <Control Id="MyBillboard" Type="Billboard" X="150" Y="150" Width="125" Height="100" >
      <Subscribe Event="SetProgress" Attribute="Progress"/>    
 </Control>
```