# Linkbutton in windows installer dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is it possible to create (prefferably with WiX) windows installer dialog with "hyperlink", which would open another dialog window?

Something like "View detailed report" in [this screenshot](http://sqlserver-qa.net/SQL2008InstallError.jpg). My google skills aren't helping with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows Installer 5.0 added a [HyperLink control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407936(v=vs.85).aspx). You can mark your installer as requiring 5.0 by setting the `InstallerVersion` attribute of the [Package](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_package.htm) element to `500`.

Note that Windows Installer 5.0 [comes with Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371185(v=vs.85).aspx), but no redistributables have been made available for earlier operating systems so far.

You can use the HyperLink control in wix by putting this XML in a custom dialog:

```
<Control Id="exampleHyperLink" 
        Height="20" Width="100" Type="Hyperlink" X="5" Y="5"> 
    <Text><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.foo.com/">Click Me</a>]]></Text> 
</Control>
```

If you need more guidance on how to create and use a custom dialog in wix, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814103/52626) where I explain how to add a warning screen.

Answer (score 2):

There are no controls native to Windows Installer that can do things like that.  What you are seeing is a WPF application running workflows and driving a UI less MSI.

You need an external UI handler.  There is still evolving technology in WiX called Burn that will help provide you with this but you'd still have to write a big chunk of it.

[WiX v3.6 Release Candidate Zero available](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/4/3/WiX-v3.6-Release-Candidate-Zero-available)