# replace click event of wix default welcome with custom handler

Tags: c#, installation, wix

in wix: i want to replace action of Welcome page of my installer to SpecialDlg  and not LicenseAgreementDlg. but using this code:

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SpecialDlg" >NOT Installed</Publish>
```

but this line dont replace the tuple in ControlEvent Table, and create new tuple instead of replacing. and the problem is : old action of Next button has not been replaced by new action. :(

[image]

thanks experts

Comment: Have you seen this: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain ?

Answer (score 1):

The button click handling is defined in the UI sequence which you refer to with the [UIRef](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_uiref.htm) element.

You can copy that UI sequence from the [wix sources](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=wix36), modify it for you own needs, and then update the `UIRef` element to point to your own customized UI sequence.

For more details, see my question/answer about [inserting a warning dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810910/how-to-display-a-non-blocking-warning-for-the-operating-system-in-wix) which is a similar scenario (though a  bit more complex because I only wanted to insert it only if a certain condition is true).